# cURL read external variable

Tags: curl

I am having trouble pushing a variable into a bash script for a cURL interrogation
I am generating an api token by using this command and pasting the token into a file:
curl -k -v -X POST --user admin:pass https://10.10.10.10/api/fmc_platform/v1/auth/generatetoken |& egrep -i '(X-auth|error)' | sed 's/.*X/X/' | grep access-token | awk '{print $2}' >token.file

The result of token.file looks like this: 237c3364-228a-475f-bf74-3b6822b53a31
I created a variable that reads the token from token.file: export tokenkey=$(cat token.file)

This token will be used later for GET/POST/PUSH, but i am not able to push this into cURL.
One example would be:
curl -k -X GET "https://10.10.10.10/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/xxxx/devices/devicerecords" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "X-auth-access-token "${tokenkey}""

I get this error: {"error":{"category":"FRAMEWORK","messages":[{"description":"Access token not found"}],"severity":"ERROR"}}

It seems that it is not reading the variable correctly.
I am not sure how to define the variable in curl in order to read the token properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no evidence it's not reading the variable correctly. There's evidence you're not following the specifications for curl options and shell syntax.

First, the syntax for an HTTP header, mostly specified in curl using `-H/--header`, **requires a colon** between the header name and value. You did this correctly for `-H "accept: application/json"` but not for `-H "X-auth-access-token ...`. Admittedly curl could be more helpful by giving an error message instead of just ignoring the bad item.

Second, it looks like you are attempting to include doublequotes in the header value, as is required for *some* header values or portions in HTTP, but the syntax you use doesn't accomplish that.

```
-H "X-auth-access-token "${tokenkey}""
#                       ^           ^ these marks are NOT part of the data
#  ^--------------------^ instead this part is quoted _to the shell_ 
#                        ^---------^ this is NOT quoted, which for a variable value
#                                    is USUALLY unsafe, but for THIS value works
#                                   ^^ and this is quoted, but empty
```

For this (UUID-format) value you don't actually need quotemarks sent in the header, but when you do need or want them you should use

```
-H "X-auth-access-token: \"${tokenkey}\""
# this sends the name WITH the colon, then the value WITH quotemarks around it
```

FYI your process of parsing the token from the response in the first command could be much simpler, but you didn't ask about that (or give example data, which would be needed)

Comment: You are right, this was the right syntax: X-auth-access-token: and I do not need the quotemarks.After correction, everything works fine.